# The library 'cardboard.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am trying to run cardboard example on my android device

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.cardboarddemo&hl=en

Giving me error "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

also I have tried to download the example from this link

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started

and I am getting the following error

trouble writing output: already prepared
The library 'cardboard.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
The following libraries were found:
- lib/armeabi-v7a/libvrtoolkit.so

My device is LG D686
with android version 4.4.2

can anyone tell me what is the problem

Comment: Same here, let's try to figure this out. What IDE do you use for debug, Eclipse ADT or Android Studio? Mind you, I can debug the original app without a trouble. But once I integrated it into another Android project, I faced this error.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse ADT, and my device is a Samsung Note 3. I think the actual device does not necessarily matter, in my case I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the project composition, settings and the IDE.

Comment: BTW, I'd use Android Studio, I successfully tried the vanilla example.